# MiniDFSCluster: HDFS triple slash schema extension wrong FS

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

I am using `defaultFS` setting in configuration of HDFS. I create configuration and then set it explicitly.

```
  import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

  val config = new Configuration()
  config.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:8020")
  val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(filePath), config)
```

Code seems to work fine most of the time, but for filePath with triple slash I get an error **only on a few machines**:

```
 Wrong FS: hdfs:/tmp/hdfstest, expected: hdfs://localhost:8020
```

One slash appears only in exception message.

Everywhere else in the system I see triple slash: `hdfs:///tmp/hdfstest`.
Also for the paths like `/tmp/hdfstest` without triple slash, defaultFS perfectly works.

Would appreciate any piece of advice. Thank you in advance!

UPD: Exception was seen in tests run on MiniDFSCluster. During the tests I used the same MiniDFSCluster with different configurations.

Comment: You should not use URI scheme if you are passing it in config

Comment: @SachinJanani oh, missed NOT in your comment. Should I just specify `localhost:8020`? Didn't make difference for my test case so far I see. Also I am very confused, why did it work for cases without triple slash.

And that's the way it is written in core-site.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out, that it was not an HDFS issue, but MiniDFSCluster test problem.
In test suite, I was creating test cluster and then checking different `defaultFS` scenarios on it.

MiniDFSCluster has some issues due to sharing of config and certain use cases can result in unexpected results and falsely failing or passing unit tests.

For more info, there is a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6360) in Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `fs.defaultFS`, you should not specify any scheme or authority, so yours paths should look like `/path/to/file`. Using a URI with a scheme, like `hdfs://localhost:port/path/to/file`, will ignore the default FS. You shouldn't ever use the HDFS scheme without a host/port like `hdfs:///` -- instead you should either rely on the default FS, or explicitly specify a host/port combination.

Comment: Do you mean that hdfs:/// shouldn't be used at all? Or in which cases?
I am very confused as I saw triple slash used (and working) a lot in EMR, Spark and so on.